# Access .NET controls from another application

Tags: .net, winapi, interprocess

I've enumerated window tree of Minesweeper (Windows 7 version) game with [EnumThreadWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPI functions and got the following (titles):

```
(Minesweeper)
\_(empty)
(GDI+ Window)
(Default IME)
```

It seems, this application now uses .NET GUI controls (based on GDI?), not enumeratesd with used WinAPI calls. How do I access .NET controls?

I need to read their values (or at least obtain images of individual components) and if possible emulate clicks.

Comment: It doesn't.  The play field is a window of the STATIC window class, a window type that is not used in .NET.  GDI+ is a C++ library.  Running corflags.exe on the .exe nails it down.  Hard to see any practical value in this question btw.

Comment: Use the accessibility interfaces.